# How to update PowerPoint chart using c#

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint

I have to update pptx file. In this pptx i have some set of chart which i have to update the data through c# code. Please let us know how to do it?

Note:
It is not OLE graph, it is power point chart component

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you are looking for with a brief example of what you are trying to do. For example it's unclear if you are looking to embed C# code, or have a standalone program process a bunch of power point slides.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA syntax it's something like

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count

    If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i).Type = msoChart Then

        Dim c As Chart
        Set c = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i).Chart

        Dim data As ChartData
        Set data = c.ChartData 
        data.Activate

        data.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B3").Value = _
            data.Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B3").Value + 1
        ...

    End If

 Next
```

An introduction can be found here: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/08/18/chart-object-model-in-word-powerpoint.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308825 Hope this helps.