# Access Chart data in PowerPoint2010 Shape & VSTO

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

I have to format Pie Chart that is located inside `Shape` (change font of Data labels, change colors inside pie chart etc). I have a code snippet:

```
        foreach (Shape s in Selection.SlideRange.Shapes)
        {
            if (s.HasChart == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {
                Excel.Workbook workbook = s.Chart.ChartData. as Excel.Workbook;
            }
        }
```

`s.Chart` is not null. However when I call `ChartData` property I get an exception:

```
's.Chart.ChartData.Workbook' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
```

How can I actually get `Chart` underlying data and properties?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember shape.Chart.ChartData is a ChartData object not an Excel.Workbook but it has a property named Workbook. You can find a short sample here: [How to update PowerPoint chart using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444491/how-to-update-powerpoint-chart-using-c-sharp/8481686#8481686)